# register MFC ocx in window 7 32bit error

Tags: windows-7, mfc, ocx

register MFC ocx in window 7 32bit error, have any solution to fix problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rYXd.jpg)

Comment: Chinese screen dumps are not exactly helpful here...sorry -1. And I'm tempted to close vote for "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `OCX` has some dependencies that are not found in the system (e.g. `mfc90.dll` or similar). Open the ocx file in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what libraries are missing. Then make sure to either deploy these libraries or link statically.